# Как обработать кириллические символы в urllib.request.urlopen()?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, urllib

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос, `urllib.request.urlopen()` не принимает кириллические символы в http запросе,
Выполняю:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://exemple.com/sent?"русский_текст"')
```

получаю:

```
self._output(request.encode('ascii'))  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Прочитав документацию по urllib.request понял, что urllib.request.urlopen() пытается перевести мой запрос в кодировку latin 1 (iso8859-1) и именно на это он и ругается, как правильно обработать запрос с кириллическими символами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/send?{0}'.format(quote_plus('"русский_текст"')))
```

или даже так:

```
urlopen(urlunparse(('http', 'example.com', '/send', None, quote_plus('"русский текст"'), None), ))
```

а вообще либой requests многие штуки чуточку удобнее делать

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло.